# Android- Difference between Open Fire , Cloud connection Server And GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi we have to implement the chat feature as part of my app. 
Earlier we have implemented a chat using xmpp protocal by integrating smack api and open fire server. Now i have looked into  [Google conncetion server](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

There GCM is sending the messages through XMPP or what. did not get any good clarity about that. but i am looking for simple solution for chat feature as we have faced some issues by using openfire server and smack library.
What is the difference between Openfire, GCM and CCS.
Which server is better for Chatting now. OPenfire or ccs .

Comment: hey @Roster , in the end what it was your solution ?, and could give me an overview of what you understood after it is implemented, and some references of interest.

Comment: @Gilberto ibarra we have continued with open fire server implementation. but now Android api it self providing the apis to implement chat feature using smack api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to be quite vague but if you're asking about the essence of the `Google Cloud Messaging` service, it can work in two ways, one is HTTP and the other one is XMPP (or the Cloud Connection Server, also known as CCS). This implies that **you** have to write your server which will manage the messages of your clients, but you can use either of the technologies I just mentioned.

From the official [GCM Cloud Connection Server](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) documentation:

> You can continue to use the HTTP request mechanism to send messages to
>   GCM servers, side-by-side with CCS which uses XMPP. Some of the
>   benefits of CCS include:
>
> The asynchronous nature of XMPP allows you to send more messages with
>   fewer resources. Communication is bidirectional—not only can your
>   server send messages to the device, but the device can send messages
>   back to your server. The device can send messages back using the same
>   connection used for receiving, thereby improving battery life. The
>   upstream messaging (device-to-cloud) feature of CCS is part of the
>   Google Play services platform. Upstream messaging is available through
>   the GoogleCloudMessaging APIs. For examples, see Implementing an
>   XMPP-based App Server.

Comment: Ok thank you. I would like to use only XMPP mechanism for chat but confusing about either i should use openfire server or CCS server.

Comment: The backend and message broadcast server is handled by google, you don't need to use openfire for this, but additionally you have to write your own server (in the language you like most, `PHP`, `Python` or whatever) that will be an interface to talk to the `Google Cloud Server` owned by Google. In other words, you have to implement the logic and you want to apply to the messages, you also need to do the subscriptors handling and use `GCM` to broadcast your messages amongst those subscriptors.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. CCS exactly replacing the need of using openfire server right.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use openfire to do this.